Did Abdullah ibn Abi Sarh apostatize for a valid reason?
My question is straightforward, If  Abdullah ibn Abi Sarh "Genuinly" had a serious doubt that caused him leaving Islam (i.e he wasn't a hypocrite but a true believer) Then how can we justify that his generous and unbiased conclusion which made him leave Islam, still to be called apostasy and treason.
We know that he was a scriber of Quran then the incident occured that he was allowed to add some words into quranic ayats by the permission of prophet Muhammad (saw) himself, isn't it a real and thought provoking on itself to doubt Islam and the prophet, I would be realistic and honest if were in place of abdullah ibn sar I would have done the same thing.
If you come with the answer that because the allowance of wording in Quran didn't really had that much siginficance in the meaning because at the end of the day it should reflect according to whole notion of Quran and doesn't contridict the quran, then I would ask isn't the Quran already the part of ( Al- kitaab) and its written and recorded along with other ( suhoof and previous scriptures) in "Lawhe Mahfooz", so hence, it must not have any other human's aditional wordings and additions to begin with.

Apostasy is defined as leaving Islam, the reason for doing it is not relevant. A mistake of Ijtihad is not a valid excuse for kufr, this is agreed upon. The claim that he was allowed to choose the wording is his claim and not necessarily true.

Qadi 'Iyad has written the following as a response to the objection regarding the apostate scribe:

فإن قلت فما معني ما روي أن عبد الله بن أبي سرح كان يكتب لرسول الله صلى
الله عليه وآله وسلم ثم ارتد مشركا وصار إلى قريش فقال لهم إني كنت أصرف
محمدا حيث أريد كان يملي علي عزيز حكيم  فأقول أو عليم حكيم؟ فيقول نعم
كل صواب، وفي حديث آخر فيقول له النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم (اكتب كذا)
فيقول أكتب كذا: فيقول: (اكتب كيف شئت) ويقول اكتب عليما حكيما فيقول
اكتب سميعا بصيرا؟ فيقول له اكتب كيف شئت
وفي الصحيح عن أنس رضي الله عنه أن نصرانيا كان يكتب للنبي صلى الله عليه
وسلم بعد ما أسلم ثم ارتد وكان يقول ما يدري محمد إلا ما كتبت له
اعلم ثبتنا الله وإياك على الحق ولا جعل للشيطان وتلبيسه الحق بالباطل
إلينا سبيلا أن مثل هذه الحكاة أولا لا توقع في قلب مؤمن ريبا إذ هي
حكاية عمن ارتد وكفر بالله ونحن لا نقبل خبر المسلم المتهم فكيف بكافر
افترى هو ومثله على الله ورسوله ما هو أعظم من هذا؟
والعجب لسليم العقل يشغل بمثل هذه الحكاية سره وقد صدرت من عدو كافر
مبغض للدين مفتر على الله ورسوله ولم يرد على أحد من السملمين ولا ذكر
أحد من الصحابة أنه شاهد ما قاله وافتراه على نبي الله وإنما يفتري الكذب
الذين لا يؤمنون بآيات الله وأولئك هم الكاذبون،
وما وقع من ذكرها في حديث أنس رضي الله عنه وظاهر حكايتها فليس فيه ما
يدل على أنه شاهدها ولعله حكى ما سمع وقد علل البزاز حديثه ذلك وقال:
رواه ثابت عنه ولم يتابع عليه، ورواه حميد عن أنس قال وأظن حميدا إنما
سمعه من ثابت، قال القاضي أبو الفضل وفقه الله ولهذا والله أعلم لم يخرج
أهل الصحيح حديث ثابت ولا حميد والحصحيح حديث عبد الله بن عزيز بن رفيع
عن أنس رضي الله عنه الذي خرجه أهل الصحة وذكرناه وليس فيه عن أنس قول شئ
من ذلك من قبل نفسه إلا من حكايته عن المرتد النصراني
ولو كانت صحيحة لما كان فيها قدح ولا توهيم للنبي صلى الله عليه وسلم
فيما أوحي إليه ولا جواز للنسيان والغلط عليه والتحريف فيما بلغه ولا طعن
في نظم القرآن وأن من عند الله إذ ليس فيه لو صح أكثر من أن الكاتب قال
له عليم حكيم أو كتبه فقال له النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم كذلك هو فسبقه
لسانه أو قلمه لكلمة أو كلمتين مما نزل على الرسول قبل إظهار الرسول لها
إذ كان ما تقدم مما أملاه الرسول يدل عليها ويقتضي وقوعها بقوة قدرة
الكاتب على الكلام ومعرفته به وجودة حسه وفطنته كما يتفق ذلك للعارف إذا
سمع البيت أن يسبق إلى قافيته أو مبتدإ الكلام الحسن إلى ما يتم به ولا
يتفق ذلك في جملة الكلام كما لا يتفق ذلك في آية ولا سورة
وكذلك قوله صلى الله عليه وسلم أن صح كل صواب فقد يكون هذا فيما فيه من
مقاطع الآي وجهان وقراءتان أنزلنا جميعا على النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم
فأملى إحداهما وتوصل الكاتب بفطنته ومعرفته بمقتضى الكلام إلى الأخرى
فذكرها للنبي صلى الله عليه وسلم فصوبها له النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم ثم
أحكم الله من ذلك ما أحكم ونسخ ما نسخ كما قد وجد ذلك في بعض مقاطيع الآى
مثله قوله تعالى: (إن تعذبهم فإنهم عبادك وإن تغفر لهم فإنك أنت العزيز
الحكيم) وهذه قراءة الجمهور وقد قرأ جماعة فإنك أنت الغفور الرحيم وليست
من المصحف
وكذلك كلمات جاءت على وجهين في غير المقاطع قرأ بهما معا الجمهور وثبتتا
في المصحف مثل (وانظر إلى العظام كيف ننشرها، وننشزها - - ويقضى اللحق،
ويقص الحق) وكل هذا لا يوجب ريبا ولا يسبب للنبي صلى الله عليه وسلم غلطا
ولا وهما وقد قيل إن هذا يحتمل
أن يكون فيما يكتبه عن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم إلى الناس غير القرآن
فيصف الله ويسميه في ذلك كيف شاء.
People might ask about the meaning of what is related about ‘Abdullah ibn Abi Sarh and the fact that he used to be one of the scribes of the Messenger of Allah, and then became an apostate and idolater and went over to Quraysh telling them that he used to change what Muhammad said whenever he wanted. He said, “He used to dictate to me, ‘Mighty, Wise’ and I would say, ‘Or Knowing, Wise,’ and he would say, ‘Yes, that is correct.’ “ In another hadith the Prophet said to him, “Knowing, Wise.” He asked, “Shall I write ‘Hearing, Seeing’?” The Prophet said, “Write whatever you like.”
In the Sahih, Anas said that a Christian used to write for the Prophet after he had become Muslim. Then he apostatised and used to say, “Muhammad only knows what I wrote for him.”
Know that stories like this do not occasion any doubt in the believer’s heart since they originate from someone who became an apostate and rejected Allah. We do not accept the traditions of the doubtful Muslim. How could we then accept them from an unbeliever who is capable of forging lies against Allah and His Messenger that are even more horrendous than this?
The wonder is that people with sound intellects can occupy themselves with stories like this when they come from unbelieving enemies of Allah who hate the deen and forge lies against Allah and His Messenger. It did not come from any of the Muslims nor did any of the Companions mention that they had witnessed what this man falsely said against the Prophet of Allah. “Those who do not believe in Allah’s Signs are merely inventing lies. It is they who are the liars.” (16:105)
What is mentioned in the hadith of Anas and the story itself do not contain anything that indicates that Anas actually saw it. Perhaps he related something he had heard. Al-Bazzar considers the hadith to be faulty and related from Thabit who is not followed. Humayd related it from Anas, and it may be that Humayd heard it from Thabit. This is why the compilers of the Sahih collections do not relate the hadith from either Humayd or Thabit. The sound hadith is that of ‘Abdullah ibn ‘Aziz ibn Rafi‘ from Anas which the people of the Sahih relate. We mentioned it above and it does not contain any statement from direct experience. Its only source is a Christian apostate.
Even if the hadith had been sound, no aspersion is cast by it nor any doubt about the Prophet regarding what was revealed to him. It is not possible for him to forget or err in it or change what had been conveyed to him. It does not constitute an attack on the composition of the Qur’an or on its being from Allah since there is nothing in the hadith beyond the fact that the scribe said to the Prophet, “Knowing, Wise,” or that he wrote it and then that the Prophet said to him. “It is like that.” His tongue or heart went ahead to one or two of the words that had been sent down on the Messenger before he manifested it. The dictation of the Messenger indicates that. It must have occurred due to the strength of the linguistic ability of the scribe, his knowledge of Arabic, and the excellence of his mind and intelligence. It is the same thing that happens when someone knowledgeable listens to verse and hastens to rhyme it, or listening to the beginning of a beautiful speech goes ahead to complete it. That does not happen with all speech as it did not happen, in this case, in every sura or ayat.
It is the same as when the Prophet, may Allah bless him and grant him peace, said, “Both of them are correct.” This can refer to two ways of reciting or two different readings of the ayats, both of which were sent down on the Prophet. He dictated one of them and the scribe, due to his intelligence and knowledge of language, added the other and then mentioned it to the Prophet who told him that it was correct. Then Allah made exact what He made exact and abrogated what He abrogated. This is found concerning parts of some ayats as for instance when He says, “If You punish them, they are Your slaves. If You forgive them, You are the Mighty, the All-Wise.” (5:118) This is what most people recite. However there is a group who recite, “You are the Ever-Forgiving, the All-Merciful.” This is not part of the recognised Qur’an.
It is the same with certain words which have come with two variations in other places. Most people recite both variations and both are confirmed in the copy of the Qur’an. An example is the ayat, “Look at the bones and how We will give them life (nunshiruha),” where we also find, “make them move (nunshizuha).” (2:259) This does not occasion any doubt nor necessitate error on the part of nor doubt about the Prophet.
It is said that this could have referred to occasions when the scribes wrote from the Prophet, may Allah bless him and grant him peace, for people in respect of what was other than the Qur’an. When the scribe did that he described Allah and named Him however he liked
— Al-Shifaa bi Ta'reef Huqooq al-Mustafaa - translation by Aisha Bewley

In summary:

The apostate made an accusation against the Prophet ﷺ to defame him, that does not mean that what he claimed was true.

If we assume that it actually happened then all the apostate did was to guess and his guess turned out to be correct. This is not proper evidence that he too received revelation or that the Prophet ﷺ did not receive revelation.

The hadith which mention this does not state that he was writing the Quran. Scribes were employed for multiple tasks, it is possible that he was writing a letter in which he was free to make changes as long as the meaning was correct.


